# Find and grep to return files without string

Tags: awk, sed, grep, find

I have the following find, sed, and grep command.

```
 find . -type d \( -name ThirdParty -o -name 3rdParty -o -name 3rd_party \) -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.bat" \) -exec grep -L 'FOO' {} \; -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e '1iFOO'
```

I want to be able to find all `.bat` files in a directory that do NOT contain the string "FOO", and pipe them to a sed command that adds the string "FOO" to the top of the file. However, when i run the find and grep portion of my command (Without sed):

```
 find . -type d \( -name ThirdParty -o -name 3rdParty -o -name 3rd_party \) -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.bat" \) -exec grep -L 'FOO' {} \; -print
```

it returns ALL bat files, even ones containing the string 'FOO'. This leads me to believe that the grep command is faulty. how can i fix this? thank you

Comment: When the file does not contain FOO, grep prints its name.  When it does, find is printing the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
grep -L 'FOO'
```

to:

```
awk '/FOO/{exit 1}'
```

so you only get the file name printed if FOO is not present in the file.

To be clear the whole command line would then be:

```
find . -type d \( -name ThirdParty -o -name 3rdParty -o -name 3rd_party \) \
    -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.bat" \) \
    -exec awk '/FOO/{exit 1}' {} \; -print0 |
        xargs -0 sed -i -e '1iFOO'
```

Comment: the command is meant to run through a directory with multiple files, not with one single file.

Comment: Right that's what the rest of your `find` command and the subsequent pipe to `sed` does. I'm just saying replace the part I show, not replace the whole command line. I updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: perfect!! one last bit, when i run this, if all of the files have 'foo' , i get  `sed: no input files`.  if possible , how can i suppress that message?

Comment: idk, that'd be a new question. `2>/dev/null` might be one brute force way but then that'd hide ALL errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `-exec` argument to `find` specifies a test: if it returns 0, the result is included; if it returns nonzero, the result is excluded. `grep -L` returns 0 regardless of whether it finds results, so it's equivalent to `-exec true \;` (or not passing `-exec` at all).

You can achieve the desired result by passing the output from your `find` command into `grep` via `xargs`: `find $find_args | xargs grep -L FOO`.

Comment: This is only returning the first file in the top directory.

Comment: @learningunix717 Strange. So your `find` command (without the `-exec ...` bit) gives all the .bat files but piping it to `xargs grep -L FOO` only gives you the first such file? And you know there are others without "FOO"?

Comment: exactly. yea i purposefully took out FOO from 3 files and then ran the command again. and it still gave me the all the bat files.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is printing the names of files that do not match (with newlines rather than nulls as a terminator).  You need to suppress the output of `grep`.  Perhaps:

```
find . -type d \( -name ThirdParty -o -name 3rdParty -o -name 3rd_party \) \
    -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.bat" \) \
    -exec sh -c '! grep -q "FOO" $1' _ {} \; -print0
```

But it seems a bit cleaner to write:

```
find . -type d \( -name ThirdParty -o -name 3rdParty -o -name 3rd_party \) \
        -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.bat" \) \
        -not -exec grep -q "FOO" {} \; -print0
```