# Find -exec awk redirect to file

Tags: awk, find, exec

I have the following script:

After finding files of specific extensions, it checks said files for whether they have a specific word or not.

```
find . -type d \( -name ThirdParty -o -name 3rdParty -o -name 3rd_party \) -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.cs" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" -o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.scala" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.js" \) -exec awk '/FOO/{f=1;exit} END{if (!f) printf "%s\0", FILENAME}' {} \;
```

I want to output the names of all files with that word into a simple text file. I have tried doing

```
find . -type d \( -name ThirdParty -o -name 3rdParty -o -name 3rd_party \) -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.cs" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" -o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.scala" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.js" \) -exec awk '/FOO/{f=1;exit} END{if (!f) printf "%s\0", FILENAME}' {} \; > output.txt
```

However, my resulting output file is empty. Thanks.

Comment: what's the difference with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242578/find-and-grep-to-return-files-without-string) question that you asked?

Comment: so in the first question I wanted to add the word if said files didn't already contain it. here, I just want to know which files are missing the word . output.txt should contain file names that don't contain the word. @downtheroad

Comment: I see, look at answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe with xargs:

```
find . -type d \( -name ThirdParty -o -name 3rdParty -o -name 3rd_party \) \
-prune -o -type f \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.cs" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" \
-o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.scala" -o -name "*.css" \
-o -name "*.js" \) | xargs grep -L word > list_of_files_missing_word.txt
```

Comment: thank you!! made some edits so that it would print only the file names and not the paths, and on new lines: `find . -type d \( -name ThirdParty -o -name 3rdParty -o -name 3rd_party \) \
-prune -o -type f \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.cs" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" \
-o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.scala" -o -name "*.css" \
-o -name "*.js" \) | xargs grep -L word | xargs -L 1 basename | sed -e 's/$/\r/g' > list_of_files_missing_word.txt`